# SUBSTRING on an Inner Join in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

One of my tables looks like the following-

[image: order table data]

One of the columns ordertype in the table has data that always has 4 characters in the beginning and then the rest of the characters are separated by ; The length of the characters vary after the ;

I am trying to use SUBSTRING to pull all the characters after the ; (semi-colon) regardless of their length. Also trying to do that for an INNER JOIN i am trying to execute. The substring in the INNER JOIN aims to pull the first 4 characters.

For some reason my query errors out. Not sure if I am doing something wrong.

Below is the sample query that I am trying to run-

```
SELECT
    ind_id,
    substring(ordertype FROM 6)
FROM
    order_table
INNER JOIN
    transaction_table
ON
    transaction_table.fileid = order_table.substring(ordertype FROM 1 FOR 4;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions in SQL are generally not called as predicates of the objects they act on.  Instead, we pass database objects to functions.  Try this version:

```
SELECT
    ind_id,
    SUBSTRING(o.ordertype FROM 6)
FROM order_table o
INNER JOIN
transaction_table t
    ON t.fileid = SUBSTRING(o.ordertype FROM 1 FOR 4);  -- chamge is here
```

Note that a possibly more robust solution here would be to use the `SPLIT_PART` function:

```
SELECT
    ind_id,
    SPLIT_PART(o.ordertype, ';', 2)
FROM order_table o
INNER JOIN
transaction_table t
    ON t.fileid = SPlIT_PART(o.ordertype, ';', 1);
```

Comment: Actually Postgres *can* call function on row types as if they were methods, but sure it is uncommon and doesn't work with the strings here.

Comment: Thanks @Tim this was really helpful.